# Nested cos() calculation in Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, recursive-query

I have table with some positive integer numbers

```
n
----
1
2
5
10
```

For each row of this table I want values `cos(cos(...cos(0)..))` (`cos` is applied n times) to be calculated **by means of SQL statement** (PL/SQL stored procedures and functions are not allowed):

```
n   coscos
--- --------
1   1
2   0.540302305868
5   0.793480358743
10  0.731404042423
```

I [can](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d039c/1) do this in Oracle 11g by using recursive queries.
Is it possible to do the same in Oracle 10g ?

Comment: why would you ever do this?  Use Oracle for what it is good at, being a database, stop making it do extra calculations.  These can very easily be offset to whatever language you like.  Further consider storing this value in the database in a separate column.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Please don't spread your religion "Use Oracle only for storing data without any calculations" in my thread  ;-)

Comment: I would hardly call that being religious about it.  The issue is you have a hammer (Oracle) and everything is a nail (solving a math problem).  This is the same thing people do with regular expressions to solve HTML parsing.  :)  The better question is why do you want to do this in Oracle, that is what performance benefit are you getting?  If you can explain that I will gladly work through a solution.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - It seems you are afraid of using full power of Oracle, so I consider it to be your religion (IMO, any religion is a set of strange restrictions).  Please discuss questions like "Is it good or bad to do math calculations in Oracle" outside this thread.

Comment: Great question Egor! I know you're asking something deeper than just calculating `COS`. I've seen your posts so I think I can assume you've already tried something with `CONNECT BY LEVEL` and it didn't work. I've got nothing here. I'd submit this to a higher authority - namely [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`MODEL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/sqlmodel.htm#g1042989) clause can solve this:

**Test data:**

```
create table test1(n number unique);
insert into test1 select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,5,10));
commit;
```

**Query:**

```
--The last row for each N has the final coscos value.
select n, coscos
from
(
    --Set each value to the cos() of the previous value.
    select * from
    (
        --Each value of N has N rows, with value rownumber from 1 to N.
        select n, rownumber
        from
        (
            --Maximum number of rows needed (the largest number in the table)
            select level rownumber
            from dual
            connect by level <= (select max(n) from test1)
        ) max_rows
        cross join test1
        where max_rows.rownumber <= test1.n
        order by n, rownumber
    ) n_to_rows
    model
    partition by (n)
    dimension by (rownumber)
    measures (0 as coscos)
    (
        coscos[1] = cos(0),
        coscos[rownumber > 1] = cos(coscos[cv(rownumber)-1])
    )
)
where n = rownumber
order by n;
```

**Results:**

```
N   COSCOS
1   1
2   0.54030230586814
5   0.793480358742566
10  0.73140404242251
```

**Let the holy wars begin:**

Is this query a good idea?  I wouldn't run this query in production, but hopefully it is a useful demonstration that any problem can be solved with SQL.

I've seen literally thousands of hours wasted because people are afraid to use SQL.  If you're heavily using a database it is foolish to not use SQL as your primary programming language.  It's good to occasionally spend a few hours to test the limits of SQL.  A few strange queries is a small price to pay to avoid the disastrous row-by-row processing mindset that infects many database programmers.

Comment: Thanks! Never used model clause before.

Answer (score 1):

Using  [`WITH FUNCTION`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1)(Oracle 12c):

```
WITH FUNCTION coscos(n INT) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   IF n > 1 
     THEN RETURN cos(coscos(n-1));
     ELSE RETURN cos(0);   
   END IF;
END;
SELECT n, coscos(n)
FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=93db55e4ee046fff01c104a315f763ac)**

Output:

```
+-----+-------------------------------------------+
| N   |                 COSCOS(N)                 |
+-----+-------------------------------------------+
|  1  |                                         1 |
|  2  | .5403023058681397174009366074429766037354 |
|  5  |  .793480358742565591826054230990284002387 |
| 10  | .7314040424225098582924268769524825209688 |
+-----+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Yes, I am fully aware of that. This question was revised, that is why I added my answer. We have 2019 and Oracle 20c is on the way.